# How to control the divs display in flex box

Tags: css, flexbox, breakpoints

I am making a blog app, you can see it here. https://6t61y.csb.app/ (for source code click the sandbox button at the bottom)

I want to show 2 cards at a time and another 2 cards below it just like [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitroot-org/frontend-intern-test/main/posts.jpeg) design. How to achieve this?

I read a couple of similar posts but nothing worked for me. (This may be a duplicate of some similar post). Is there any thumb rule to remember always for such kind of problems because I as a beginner encounter this problem on regular basis?

Note: I am not using any external UI libraries like bootstrap of material UI. So I can't use Grid item sm=6 sm=6 kind of technique.

Comment: If you want answers *here*, present enough of the problem *here* to give a useful answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I forked your sandbox and created my own that successfully creates your wanted design. You can see it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-merkle-e8gz5).

The reason that this works is because in the child element, I put:

```
flex: 1 0 40%;
```

This is shorthand for the following properties:

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-basis: 40%;
```

The reason that I set the flex-basis to 40% is to account for the margin of 2vh that you are adding. Without that margin, it could be set to 50% but they would be stuck right next to each other. This number can be increased or decreased depending on your and your website's needs.

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is the resource that I would highly recommend to you to continue learning about flexbox. It is very comprehensive and explains each and every single property (I have absolutely no affiliation with this website, it's just the one that taught me almost everything I know about flexbox).

Comment: Thankyou so much! I will surely read the provided resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) in CSS and divide into 2 column using `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)` or `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr`

```css
.parent {
  margin: 4rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
}

.child {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"> Card </div>
  <div class="child"> Card </div>
  <div class="child"> Card </div>
  <div class="child"> Card </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not be using boottrap or material-ui etc, but you can also create a simple reusable component.

```
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
const Grid = ({ container, item, children, ...props }) => {
  const size = useMemo(() => {
    switch (props.size) {
      case 2:
        return "50%";
      case 3:
        return "33.3333%";
      default:
        return "100%";
    }
  }, [props]);

  if (container) {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: "flex", maxWidth: "100%", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }

  if (item) {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexBasis: size, maxWidth: size }}>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return null;
};

export default Grid;
```

Then use it like

```
    <Grid container>
        <Grid item> 
          <Card />
        </Grid>      
        <Grid item size={2}>
          <Card />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item size={2}>
          <Card />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item size={3}>
          <Card />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item size={3}>
          <Card />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item size={3}>
          <Card />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
```

codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-dewdney-stbq0?file=/src/App.js

Note: you may replace style with CSS.
Note: Change your card css width to '100%';